# Bootstrap 4 dynamic tooltip with custom class

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, tooltip

I create a dynamic tootltip on target element in the following way :

```
var dynamicTooltip = new bootstrap.Tooltip($(targetElement));
```

Everything work just fine, but i would like to add to the generated tooltip a custom class.
Is not clear to me how can i target to the html generated by bootstrap with the previous instruction (or better which bootstrap API should i use to attach a class).
I see that bootstrap tooltip have a class named "tooltip" but i can't use that class to find my newly generated element eg :

```
$(".tooltip")
```

In fact i am afraid that the code above will find also already existing tooltip, and i want target only the newly generated one.

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From bootstrap docs:

[Here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/#options)

You can use the `template` option to give complex HTML structure, or just the `customClass` option to add custom classes:

```
var dynamicTooltip = new bootstrap.Tooltip($(targetElement), {
    customClass: 'myCustomClass'
});
```

Comment: you are right, i read directly the method documentation, and forgot to better check configuration section of documentation. Thanks a lot